# Filename gets changed + Blackberry mail

Tags: blackberry

In my application i have to record a voice and send the recorded voice as an attachment to the client's server. I am using Transport.send(message) to send the email from within the application. 
Now the problem that i am facing is that if the name of the recorded file is  "abc.amr", it gets  changed to something like "utf-8BdGVzdC5hbXI" on client server. The name gets garbled on client's server. However if I append ".amr" to the garbled file, it plays correctly. This is case not only with sound file but with any kind of file i attach (image, text etc.).
I also tried to send the mail separately using Blackberry email client, in that also the sme behaviour is seen. Can any suggest what should i add in my code to make it work correctly or any external changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the mail server is renaming the attachments. If you would like to send your file name correctly, how about adding it as a Subject or Body of the email

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Actually the problem is that this application is built on iPhone, Android and Blackberry. The emails sent from Android and iPhone do not have any problems. The problem is only with email sent from Blackberry.

Comment: Is it the BES which is renaming the attachment?

Comment: Thank you rfsk2010. The problem was with their email server.It got corrected now. Thank you for the help.